# how to access controller's method when user try to access image/pdf file by URL

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am working on the CodeIgniter project. where I want to access image/pdf file by URL only if the user is logged in otherwise.it should be redirected to an error page like 404.

what I did till now.

I have created a route to call a method in my controller like below.

```
/*site_url() = http://siteurl.com/assets/pdf_docs/12456.pdf*/

$route['assets/pdf_docs/(:any)'] = 'tracking/pdfTracker/$1';
```

But it is not calling method in `tracking` controller.What i am thinking is that i can authenticate session in `pdfTracker` method like below.

```
 public function pdfTracker($fileName){

        if($this->session->userdata('userdata')){

            //user can show file
        }else{

            redirect('show_404');
        }

  }
```

If any Query please drop a comment.

Comment: what error u got? try with this to check ur url is working or not : `public function pdfTracker($fileName)
{
    echo $fileName;die;
}`

Comment: I am not getting any error. It's just opening file passed in URL.